# Why does my javascript file not use the data in my text file?

Tags: javascript, html

My JS:

```js
function updateDisplay() {
    var url = 'data.txt';

    fetch(url).then(function(response) {
        response.text().then(function(text) {

            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.open('GET', url);
            request.responseType = 'text';

            text = request.response;

            textArr = text.split("\n")
            request.onload = function() {
                document.getElementById('con').textContent = textArr[0];
                document.getElementById('new').textContent = textArr[1];
                document.getElementById('dec').textContent = textArr[2];
                document.getElementById('unr').textContent = textArr[3];
                document.getElementById('rec').textContent = textArr[4];
            };
            request.send();

        });    
    });

};

window.onload = function(){
    updateDisplay();
}
```

HTML:

```html
        <p id="con" style="color: rgb(101, 221, 155); font-family: robotobold; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; border-bottom: 0; font-size: 50px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
               data1</p>
        <p style="color: #D4E1E4; font-size: 18px; font-family: robotoregular; font-weight: regular; border-bottom: 0; text-align: center;">
               <b>con</b></p>
        <p id="new" style="color: #FF9D00; font-family: robotobold; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; border-bottom: 0; font-size: 50px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
                data2</p>
        <p style="color: #D4E1E4; font-size: 18px; font-family: robotoregular; font-weight: regular; border-bottom: 0; text-align: center;">
                <b>new</b></p>
        <p id="dec" style="color: #F65164; font-family: robotobold; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; border-bottom: 0; font-size: 50px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
                data3</p>
        <p style="color: #D4E1E4; font-size: 18px; font-family: robotoregular; font-weight: regular; border-bottom: 0; text-align: center;">
                <b>dec</b></p>
        <p id="unr" style="color: rgb(248, 245, 64); font-family: robotobold; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; border-bottom: 0; font-size: 50px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
                data4</p>
        <p style="color: #D4E1E4; font-size: 18px; font-family: robotoregular; font-weight: regular; border-bottom: 0; text-align: center;">
                <b>unr</b></p>
        <p id="rec" style="color: rgb(68, 155, 226); font-family: robotobold; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; border-bottom: 0; font-size: 50px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
                data5</p>
        <p style="color: #D4E1E4; font-size: 18px; font-family: robotoregular; font-weight: regular; border-bottom: 0; text-align: center;">
                <b>rec</b></p>
```

However, the text on screen doesn't change.

When I console.log(textArr), it prints out the correct data.
When I console.log(textArr[1], it prints out the correct data.
And so on...

The problem is that the elements 'new' downwards don't change.

What's wrong here?

Comment: Why on earth are you `fetch`ing a URL and then, when you have the data from the URL, getting it with `XMLHttpRequest`? That's like getting in a car, doing the shopping, going home, throwing the shopping away, then getting in a *different (older) car* and doing the shopping again!

Answer (score 1):

You try to read the response from the XMLHttpRequest object…

> ```
>         text = request.response;
>
>         textArr = text.split("\n")
> ```

… **outside** the `onload` event handler. i.e. before the response has arrived.

Comment: what would be the way that you do it - i moved them into the onload handler, but nothing has changed.

Comment: @LiamWilliamson — Given the correction you described, the code works when I test it.